# Linux hard drive speed test

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk

I would like a lhard drive
speed test software.  I have tried black magic but it doesn't appear to support Linux.
What are my options?

Comment: Try [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance) - works well and on SSDs/M.2 drives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) is the most comprehensive testing and benchmarking platform available for the Linux operating system. The process from the benchmark installation, to the actual benchmarking, to the parsing of important hardware and software components is heavily automated and completely repeatable, asking users only for confirmation of actions. It is possible to log in real-time various system sensors like the CPU temperature, the battery power consumption, disk read/write speeds, and numerous other sensors. This can be done while any test profile is running and the recorded results are then provided within the results viewer.

The Phoronix Test Suite is licensed under the GNU GPLv3 free software license.

Supported platforms are Linux, Windows, OS X, GNU Hurd, Solaris and BSD operating systems. Phoronix Test Suite can be downloaded as a .deb package or .tar.gz package from the official [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/?k=downloads) website. Phoronix Test Suite is in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, and can be installed using the command:

```
sudo apt install phoronix-test-suite
```

Comment: I'm using Debian/ubuntu so when I get a chance to test this question I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `time` in front of some DD commands, read from /dev/zero or a CD/DVD iso and output to drive, read from drive and output to /dev/null

```
user@darkstar ~ $ time  dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile bs=1024 count=1024000
1024000+0 records in
1024000+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 9.9741 s, 105 MB/s

real    0m10.093s
user    0m0.064s
sys 0m2.096s
```

Comment: Could you post a complete command you would use with time for completion sake?